# Laptop died after using a SATA/IDE USB hard drive converter

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, usb, power-supply, sata

So I think I have done something very bad, I have a HP laptop and wanted to recover some data from some old SATA and IDE drives.

I Bought this http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00VR52ZZ0?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00

After trying just the USB with an IDE 3.5 drive USB only it did not power on I then used a desktop power supply (4 pin) to power the drive but then my laptop switched off and I am worried I have fried the laptop hard drive.

The IDE drive i used was set to primary so maybe this could have overwritten my laptops hard drive?

Now my laptop will not boot, when i press the power button the light power light flashes on and then off then the fan spins very loudly likes its overheated and stays like that.

Is it possible that a power surge has hit my laptop?

Comment: You connected the drive to the power supply of a desktop that was running and connected the adapter and to your laptop?

Comment: did you tried to power on your laptop without hdd? im not pretty sure abour what you did, can you be more clear please :S?

Comment: Ramhound,    
 
You connected the drive to the power supply of a desktop that was running and connected the adapter and to your laptop? Yes that is correct was that stupid, so I used the desktop to power the HDD then connected the HDD via the converter to my laptop via USB

Comment: did you tried to power on your laptop without hdd? im not pretty sure abour what you did, can you be more clear please :S? Sorry my laptop is running windows 8.1, i connected an old HDD to my laptop via the converter and HDD was powered by a desktop computer

Comment: I thought that had to be done so the HDD had power as the converter was USB it didnt hold enough power

Comment: 3,5 drive(powered by desktop > adapter usb to sata > to laptop's usb?????

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Also the drive i tried to get data from was set to primary so plugging this into a running windows laptop would this cause a big issue?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the adapter may have done permanent damage to your laptop. USB ports normally have a fuse to prevent short circuits but this may not have prevented 12V being fed back into the laptop.

Comment: That makes sense thanks James, its within 12 month warranty so I will try and play dumb and just say it wont switch on!

Comment: I feel stupid i should have done some research first, i kind of thought it would be simple.

Comment: The setting to  primary will have made no difference when used via USB. That is only for an IDE connection.

Comment: I have powered hard drives from another pc many times to get data off to another pc using usb adapters, never had a problem. Its possible the adapter you bought was defective and caused your issue, not you.

Comment: Thanks all, Moab my laptop does come on so to speak but the fan just runs non stop like it's trying to cool down left the battery out over 24 hours but no joy. Do you think something internal has fried?